# Geometry problems in complex plane

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, vectors

What is it like when geometry problems are expressed in terms of complex planes?

Comment: I think this question, ‘what is it like’ cannot really be answered on math.SE. maybe you can try discussing in the math chat room

Answer (score 1):

Defining
$$
a \cdot b = \frac{\overline{a} b + a \overline{b}}{2} \\
a \times b = \frac{\overline{a} b - a \overline{b}}{2 i}
$$

These properties are obtained;
$$
\begin{align}
a \cdot b =& a_r b_r + a_i b_i \\
a \times b =& a_r b_i - a_i b_r \\
r_1 e^{i \theta_1} \cdot r_2 e^{i \theta_2} =& r_1 r_2 \cos (\theta_2 - \theta_1) \\
r_1 e^{i \theta_1} \times r_2 e^{i \theta_2} =& r_1 r_2 \sin (\theta_2 - \theta_1)
\end{align}
$$

Using this, I got the equivalence of following geometry problems in complex planes.

1. Intersection of two lines.

The intersection $p$ of two lines $z = a + b s$, $z = c + d t$ (s,t are real parameters) is

$$
p = \frac{(c \times d) b - (a \times b) d}{b \times d}
$$

The elegant way to derive this is to compare $a - c + b s - d t = 0$ with Jacobi identity;
$$
 x (y \times z) + y (z \times x) + z (x \times y) = 0 
$$

2. Intersection of a line and a circle.

The intersections $p_{\pm}$ of the line $z = a + b t$ and the circle $z = r e ^{i \theta}$ (t,$\theta$ are real parameters) is

Defining
$$
h = \frac{a \times b}{|b|}
$$
,
$$
p_{\pm} = \frac{b}{|b|} \left(- i h \pm \sqrt{r^2 - h^2} \right)
$$

3. Intersection of two circles.

The intersections $p_{\pm} $ of the circles $z = r_0 e^{i \theta_0}$ and $z = r_1 e^{i \theta_1} + a$ is

Defining

$$
\begin{align}
r_+ &= r_0 + r_1 \\
r_- &= r_0 - r_1 \\
s &= |a| + \frac{r_+ r_-}{|a|} \\
t &= |a| - \frac{r_+ r_-}{|a|} \\
e &= \sqrt{\left(|a| - \frac{r_+^2}{|a|}\right)\left(|a| - \frac{r_-^2}{|a|}\right)}
\end{align}
$$
,
$$
p_{\pm} = \frac{a}{2 |a|} (s \pm e)
$$